# Metro UI - Image with UniformToFill has 1px gap (or semi-transparent pixel column)

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have an Image element inside a Grid cell with a background colour set. The Image element has Stretch="UniformToFill" and HorizontalAlignment/VerticalAlignment set to "Center". In this configuration, in some instances (this is a tiled DataTemplate), 1px of the Grid's background shows through on the left hand side of the image.

I've tried UseLayoutRounding on the root element (and elsewhere) to no avail. It's hard to tell if it's to do with sub-pixel positioning/sizing from inspection alone, so I can't be sure if this is the cause.

Whilst I would of course love a magic fix, I would welcome any speculative theories as to the cause of the problem regardless of a solution if only to provide a basis for further research/fiddling.

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: Could it be that the image does not have the same width/height ratio as the control it's hosted within? UniformToFill means "take up all the space without distorting (changing width/height ratio) the image: